# How to communicate with a shell session via Java

Tags: java, shell

I'd like to run some shell command in a java program. But I don't want to launch the shell script as a Process and capture its output. I just wonder is there any existing library to launch a shell session in java and communicate with it ? Some kind of library that I can use API directly. such as following. Thanks

```
Shell shell = new Shell();
String output = shell.execute("pwd");
String errorOutput = shell.execute("wrong command");
```

Comment: You will need to use a Process, what's the issue using it?

Comment: "I don't want to launch the shell script as a Process and capture its output"  -- "launch a shell session in java and communicate with it". How are those two statements different? Can you explain your question a little more?

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you can use Runtime.getRuntime().exec to execute shell commands.

It's a pretty easy to use it.

Here you have a very good tutorial:
https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/

Answer (score -1):

The class [ProccessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) might help.

I also followed [Mkyong tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-execute-shell-command-from-java/) once and it was really useful.